# How can I split this string so that it keeps quotes and brackets together?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split out a string based on spaces, except if the text is wrapped in `( )` brackets or `' '` quotes.

e.g.

```
SELECT (name, age) FROM marks WHERE name == 'mark smith';
```

would split into:

```
[SELECT, (name, age), FROM, marks, WHERE, name, ==, 'mark smith', ;]
```

My current regex splits it into:

```
[SELECT, (name, age), FROM, marks, WHERE, name, ==, 'mark, smith', ;]
```

i.e. splits the mark smith quotes.

My regex is currently this: `"\\s+(?![^(]*\\))"` and I have tried adding a bit for `' '` quotes, but haven't had any success yet!

Comment: It's better to use an SQL parser for this requirement.

Comment: I'm trying to build a cut down SQL database for an assignment and so need to do it myself sadly!

Comment: The string isn't tooooo important, its more I just want to keep bracketed and quoted strings together when splitting by spaces :)

Comment: Include an escaped quote in your not statement. Not sure if that's the right vernacular I'm not a regex guy really.

Comment: In PCRE you could use `([^\s"'()]+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|\(([^(]*)\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\s` - one of my favourite uses for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)|'.*?'|\\w+|[^('\\s\\w]+");
String s = "SELECT (name, age), (a, b) FROM marks WHERE name=='mark smith' or b <> 'Y';";
String[] r = pat.matcher(s).results().map(m -> m.group()).toArray(String[]::new);
for (String e : r)
    System.out.println(e);
```

output:

```
SELECT
(name, age)
,
(a, b)
FROM
marks
WHERE
name
==
'mark smith'
or
b
<>
'Y'
;
```

Comment: This is also very helpful as I do have examples with commas in so this helps me too. Thank you!

Comment: How would I alter this so that it can still split out name=='mark smith' into: name, ==, 'mark smith' ? Is that possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern matcher:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "SELECT (name, age) FROM marks WHERE name == 'mark smith';";
        var pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)|'.*'|\\w+|={1,2}");
        var matcher = pattern.matcher(query);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
SELECT
(name, age)
FROM
marks
WHERE
name
==
'mark smith'
```

Comment: Hi Akif, that looks mostly great, thanks! How would i be able to edit it to I keep the == token, that one is important (and can be any operator, e.g. >, <, != etc)

Comment: Give me example?

Comment: In my original string I had a == operator and in your output, that is missing. I am trying to keep the == operator in the output as I need it to carry out the query? So I would just need == between name and 'mark smith' :)

Comment: Looks like this would work: Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)|'.*'|==|\\w+") - Thanks!

Comment: Also you can use: Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)|'.*'|\\w+|={1,2}");

Comment: This means = or ==, if you want only == you can use {2,2}